# html form with a php

Tags: php, xhtml

This is xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile     

1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title> Order </title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Chose car: 
<form method="GET" action="aa.php"
<select name="sastojci[]">
<option name="sastojci[]" value="ma">Mazda sp 25</option>
<option name="sastojci[]" value="op">Opel Karl</option>
<option name="sastojci[]" value="me">Mercedes Cla</option>
<option name="sastojci[]" value="da">Dacia Sandero</option>
<option selected="selected" name="sastojci[]" value="ja">Jaguar XJ</option>
<option name="sastojci[]" value="pe">Peugeot 308</option>
</select>
<br/>
How many cars you want: 
<input type="text" name="kolicina" maxlength="3" value="3"/> .<br />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is part of php file:

```
<?php echo $_GET["sastojci[]"]; 
 echo $_GET["narudzba"]; ?>
```

When you press submit button blank page appears.
Something wrong with xhtml file but do not know what.
What should i change?

Comment: You try to access parameters, via `GET` that your form sends via `POST`

Comment: name="sastojci[]" is not needed in your option. Remove that from all the options and keep it in the select tag.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) and then var_dump($_POST) in your PHP and you should see the problem.

Comment: You should look at an HTML form tutorial there are a lot of issues with this form. To start `<form method="post" action="aa.php"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form

Answer (score 0):

Get grabs the variables from the URL where as post "posts" them in the header. Your issue is that you are posting the variables in the header while the php page is trying to get them from the URL. Instead of $_GET use $_POST.